# Var_dump() Displays String, echo()/print_r() Returns Nothing

Tags: php, html-parsing, simple-html-dom

I am using a Simple HTML DOM Parser library to parse URLs with a DOCTYPE tag. I'm able to reach the required tag but whenever I echo or try storing the results it doesn't show me anything. However, var_dump() shows me the required string.

```
require_once("simpledom.php");

$url="http://google.com";
$sPage = file_get_contents($url);
$sPageContent = new simple_html_dom();
$sPageContent->load($sPage);
$sObjects = $sPageContent->find('unknown');

foreach($sObjects as $sKey)
{
    var_dump($sKey->_[4]); /*this var_dump shows the stuff */
    $showres = $sKey->_[4]
}

/* this variable should hold the string but it shows nothing */
echo $showres;
```

Comment: What's the type var_dump shows you?

Comment: var_dump shows me   string '<!doctype html>' (length=15)

Comment: Have you tried to echo within the loop like are  you are doing var_dump?

Comment: If you echo just that on your browser, you will not see anything... What do you want to do exactly?

Comment: @bub strange thing is, it wont show anything in the browser window, but it pops up in source window as <!doctype html>

Comment: @PeterPan666 I want to store it as a string.

Comment: If you want to store everything that you parse in your loop you should do something like `$showres .= $sKey->_[4];`. Don't know if it's the desired behavior though, try to clarify your question by editing it. Like what is you desired output...

Comment: and its solved. Thank you so much guys for your precious time. @chris85 is the man, he nailed the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `<!doctype html>` is outputted the browser reads that as an element so you need to encode the `<` and `>` symbols. PHP has a function already built for that, http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php.

So your code should be:

```
echo htmlspecialchars($showres);
```

which in your source will give you

```
&lt;!doctype html&gt;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo htmlentities($showres);
```

will echo what's in `$showres` and replace all HTML markup with HTML entities so you can see the string and not let the browser use it as a markup.

Not sure what you're trying to do though.

Answer (score -2):

try casting the value to a string

```
$showres = (string)$sKey->_[4];
```

Besides, your echo is after your loop

Comment: It is a string already OP said; `var_dump shows me string '<!doctype html>' (length=15) `.

Comment: Sorry @David, it didnt help